# spark streaming rdd to json output without deprecation

Tags: json, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-streaming, rdd

Below code snippet : df5 dataframe prints json correctly but isStream is false also this is deprecated in spark 2.2.0 ,so i tried with  another approach in last two line of code, but its not able to read json correctly, any suggestion ??

```
val unionStreams = ssc.union(kinesisStreams)
unionStreams.foreachRDD ((rdd: RDD[Array[Byte]], time: Time) => {
  val rowRDD = rdd.map(jstr => new String(jstr))
  val schema = StructType(StructField("clientTime",StringType,nullable= true) :: StructField("clientIPAddress",  StringType,nullable = true) :: Nil)

  val df5 = sqlContext.read.schema(schema).json(rowRDD)
  println(df5.isStreaming)

  val df6 = spark.readStream.schema(schema).json(rdd.toString())
  println(df6.isStreaming) )}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `Dataset[String]`:

```
import sqlContext.implicits._

sqlContext.read.schema(schema).json(rowRDD.toDS)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, There will be no warning.

```
val df5 = sqlContext.read.schema(schema).json(spark.createDataset(rowRDD)(Encoders.STRING))
```